# How can I make my workflow faster (edit mode)?

Tags: workflow

**Hello**
I am slowly getting used to Blender. 
[image]
[image]
at this moment I am doing each ,lets call it "a cut" separately ,Selecting both sides of an object in edit mode ,4 Faces
Then I am using **Ctrl + F** ,**Inset Faces** ,seems to be faster then simply pressing **I** .Don't ask me why .I know that's kinda weird...
So after **Inset Faces** ,I input **0.075** (75mm) **Enter** ( ***#1*** ) ,**X** I choose **Faces** After that I select *4* vertexes and I make a Face (**F**) ,going around and repeating that ( ***#2*** ) ,then **Alt**+**RMB** a corner in *Face mode* then **Ctrl + F** ,Input 0.025 **Enter** ( ***#3*** ) ,**Ctrl+F Tab** input **0.05** **Enter** 
**TAB** then i input *0.075* ,**Enter** ( ***#4*** ).
I'm looking for some tips on how i can do this faster ,without using Modifiers ,too early for modifiers.
Sorry for the mess ,I am not used to this kind of formatting

Comment: Your question would be much clearer if you [edit] it with 2 images of "before" and "after" your procedure, maybe some images with steps in between. For now I don't quite see how image above is related here

Comment: I don't see a reason why deleting faces and recreating them on step 2, skipping that and just extruding inwards, then scaling bottom faces would be faster. What do you want to do faster for the rest?

Comment: Mr Zak Well I am asking is there a faster way to do other sections ,can I just duplicate it (shift + D) ,sometimes I am afraid to try stuff ,no idea why but yeah I completely forgot that you can extrude but how I properly connect the lower and top faces ,the only way I know its to get rid of the top and lower faces and then do Fills with the F ,when selecting 4 vertexes.

Comment: If you duplicate geometry it will be unconnected from the original one. You can then scale it a bit down, select border edge loops of both pieces and run Bridge Edge Loops, this might fit in your situation or might not - I'm not sure as I can't really imagine the whole situation. In general I'd advise you to experiment on a simple file and see what you can actually do, as well as looking modeling tutorials.